# How the browser determine to display the first paint?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Recently I just do some work about Server Side Render. And I met a problem which I can't find its real logic.

In common cases, browsers will display content when the script is loading which is before `</body>`.

```
<body>
   <div>Our Content</div>
   <script src="xxx.js"></script>
</body>
```

But I met a case that chrome will display the first paint after the script which is small or cached finished loading and running.

I use Chrome Development Tools to see Page Performance. When I open the Network Throtting, it will display the first paint before the JavaScript loaded and run. However if script is loaded when chrome parsing HTML, chrome will run the script, then display the first paint.

The above is a easy case. But how the browser determine to display the first paint in different cases?

Comment: This really *feels like* a gigantic, broad [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).  Is there any ***practical application*** that you are working with that requires you to know or care about the browser's internal order of operations?

Comment: Maybe i really fall into a XY Problem. I just want to know  how does the browser decide that it's time to display first screen. It's important because I am doing Server Side Render and if the browser will display after the script loaded and run, SSR was no meaningful.